# How to implement the basic Authentication in spring boot security for same endpoints for multiple users

Tags: java, spring-boot, basic-authentication

I need help to implement the basic authentication for same endpoints for multiple users

Endpoint :http://localhost:8080/function/id/?user=&id=

User is the request parameter and the application sends different users in the request .Based on the users  and different credentials needs to be configured  .Can any one help me how to implement the spring boot implementation for different users .

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;


    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        String role =environment.getProperty("role");
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/id/").hasRole(role)
                .antMatchers("/login/").hasRole(role)
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
    @Bean

    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {

        String username = environment.getProperty("username");
        String password =environment.getProperty("password");
        String role =environment.getProperty("role");

        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder().encode(password);
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername(username).password(encodedPassword).roles(role).build());
        return manager;
    }
   @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is **not** basic authentication, basic auth uses request headers not parameters.

Answer (score 3):

To be able to authorize multiple users you have to store multiple credentials somewhere.

Usually credentials are stored in a database. To do that you would have to configure connection to your database and then use `JdbcUserDetailsManager` instead of `InMemoryUserDetailsManager` ([Spring Doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/provisioning/JdbcUserDetailsManager.html)). There are many resources on how to configure database connection in Spring Boot, for example: https://springhow.com/spring-boot-database-connection/. In a simple case adding `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` starter, a connnector (depending on the database you use) and some configuration properties is enough.

If you still want to test your application with in-memory user credentials you can do that as well. Instead of feeding the user details manager with one user account defined in the application properties you could, for example, define a map with multiple username / password pairs and that put all of that in the in-memory user details manager (by calling `InMemoryUserDetailsManager#createUser` for each credential pair that you've defined).

Another thing is authorizing requests. If I understood you correctly you want to use HTTP Basic Authentication. With basic auth credentials are usually passed in an Authorization HTTP Header. Value of that header should have a following format: `Basic base64(username:password)`. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication).

There are many options in Spring Security to configure your authentication flow, but the one with using UserDetailsManager requires the least custom configuration if your security flow is simple enough.

Example code using `JdbcUserDetailsManager` (omitted other fragments):

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsManager userDetailsManager()
    {
        JdbcUserDetailsManager jdbcUserDetailsManager = new JdbcUserDetailsManager();
        jdbcUserDetailsManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
    
        return jdbcUserDetailsManager;
    }

}
```

You also need matching SQL schema to work with the manager:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS   
(
    USERNAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PASSWORD VARCHAR(68) NOT NULL,
    ENABLED TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(USERNAME)
);
CREATE TABLE AUTHORITIES
(
    USERNAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    AUTHORITY VARCHAR(68) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (USERNAME) REFERENCES USERS(USERNAME)
);
```

Note that you need to store passwords encrypted with the same algorithm that is configured in your `PasswordEncoder` bean (bcrypt in your example). Best option would be to create the users from the Spring application itself and use the `PasswordEncoder` bean for encoding the passswords.

You can find more details in an article [here](https://www.javainterviewpoint.com/spring-security-jdbcuserdetailsmanager-example/).

#### Loading lists from properties

You can store your list of users in the properties file and use Spring Boot to load it into objects.

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "data")
public class DataProperties {

    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();    

    // getters and setters

    public static class User {
        private String username;
        private String password;
        private String role;

        // getters and setters
    }
}
```

Enable configuration properties binding and inject them into your `UserDetailsService` bean definition:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(DataProperties.class)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter 
{

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(DataProperties properties) {
        // load users into user details manager
    }
}
```

Properties:

```
data.users[0].username=john
data.users[0].password=123456
data.users[0].role=admin
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response .But I am not using any database and keeping the passwords in application.properties  as below       .Could you please suggest without the database                                
spring.data.username= user
spring.data.password=XXXXXXXXX
spring.data.role=USER

Comment: You can load more complex structures from properties easily using Spring Boot's @ConfigurationProperties. [Article on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot). I've added an example of how it can look like in your scenario to the answer.